# GameObject Position Within Another GameObject Issues

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject

I'm trying to instantiate an object at the position of a GameObject within another GameObject. I want a bullet to fire from a GameObject called bulletStart within my Player GameObject. I can get it to instantiate from the bulletStart GameObject position but when I want to move the bulletStart object to a new position based on Player's animation that is playing, the bullet will not instantiate at all:

```
void Fire ()
    {

        if(anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Player_Shoot_Side"))
        {
            bulletStartX = bulletStart.transform.position.x;
            bulletStartY = bulletStart.transform.position.y;

            if (transform.localScale.x > 0)
            {
                bullet.GetComponent<BulletBehaviour>().bulletSpeed = 50;
                Instantiate(bullet, new Vector3(bulletStartX, bulletStartY, 0f), transform.rotation);
            }
            else if (transform.localScale.x < 0)
            {
                bullet.GetComponent<BulletBehaviour>().bulletSpeed = -50;
                Instantiate(bullet, new Vector3(bulletStartX, bulletStartY, 0f), transform.rotation);
            }

        }

     }
```

But it will instantiate with the following code:

```
void Fire ()
    {
        bulletStartX = bulletStart.transform.position.x;
        bulletStartY = bulletStart.transform.position.y;

        if (transform.localScale.x > 0)
        {
           bullet.GetComponent<BulletBehaviour>().bulletSpeed = 50;
           Instantiate(bullet, new Vector3(bulletStartX, bulletStartY, 0f), transform.rotation);
        }
        else if (transform.localScale.x < 0)
        {
           bullet.GetComponent<BulletBehaviour>().bulletSpeed = -50;
           Instantiate(bullet, new Vector3(bulletStartX, bulletStartY, 0f), transform.rotation);
        }
     }
```

The Player animation for shooting from the side is called Player_Shoot_Side in the Animation editor

Comment: Well the only variable between your two examples is `anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Player_Shoot_Side")` which return `false` I guess.

Have you tried to step into with a Debugger or add some `Debug.Log`

Comment: I added a Debug.Log line in to see if the animation isn't playing using if(!anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Player_Shoot_Side")) and it is showing the debug message I set. Which is strange because the animation IS playing

Comment: From this http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimatorStateInfo.IsName.html
`The name should be in the form Layer.Name, for example "Base.Idle".`

Comment: the animation is named as Player_Shoot_Side so should I rename it to Base.Player_Shoot_Side?

Comment: Why don't you just put a breakpoint there? or at least debug.log the name of the animation?

Answer (score 0):

1). Most probably your animation is on the base layer, so you should check for "`Base Layer.Player_Shoot_Side"` instead of "`Player_Shoot_Side`".
2). Make sure that `"Player_Shoot_Side"` is the state name and not the animation name. (Click on the state that has you animation in the Animator and use that name)

You should have something like

```
anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Base Layer.State name")
```

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationLayers.html

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-State.html